# How can you automate the Nuget Services manager from EnvDTE in a command line tool?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, envdte

I am building a command line tool which I can use to automate Nuget upgrades using Nuget Package Manager.

Here what I have got so far based on suggestion from http://sammyageil.com/post/create-visual-studio-solution-and-add-project-using-code and 
http://docs.nuget.org/create/invoking-nuget-services-from-inside-visual-studio.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dte = (DTE) Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("VisualStudio.DTE.12.0", true), true);
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Working with {0},{1} edition", dte.FullName, dte.Edition);
        dte.SuppressUI = false;
        dte.UserControl = false;

        IServiceProvider provider = ServiceProvider.CreateFromSetSite((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte);
        var componentModel = (IComponentModel)provider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        IVsPackageInstallerServices installerServices = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstallerServices>();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Error.Write(e);
    }
    dte.Quit();
}
```

Problem I am having is when I cast the object received from provider.GetService with IComponentModel interface it throws the below exception, which I have not clue as to what its saying.

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.IComponentModel'. 
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the 
interface with IID '{605AF649-8844-3F09-9982-1258074BE833}' 
failed due to the following error: No such interface supported 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Can some one please help me understand what it says and may be also suggest me on the right path.